# Note2 Update to 4.4

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I linked my phone Samsung note2 with my PC , I find there is a new Update for the phone.
the problem kies don't tell me wich version is avaible.

I want to update my phone directly to kitkat 4.4 because 4.3 I think there is some problems with it.

Kies give me just some information about the update but I want to know if the update shown on the picture is 4.4 or 4.3 please help !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDA:NA1 firmware is kitkat 4.4.2